# Combining Regexes

Tags: regex

How can I combine regexes?

EDIT: This if for exam preparation. The question is write a regex to find all strings that have an odd number of a's and an even number of b's?

i.e. instead of | for OR, I need a mechanism to emulate AND

I have two regexes:

```
1) to find odd number of a's:

^[^a]*a([^a]*a[^a]*a)*[^a]*$

2) to find even number of b's:

^([^b]*b[^b]*b)*[^b]*$
```

Comment: Whilst it is probably possible to construct such a regex, it will be very complicated (remember that a regex is just a state machine that is clocked once for every input character).  You are probably better off running two separate regexes, and ANDing the results.

Comment: I totally agree with Oli, but I'm curious about the actual answer :-)

Comment: It is possible to construct such a regex [with the same principles the existing ones are constructed with, only more so], but not by combining the two existing regexes with some operator (except maye in perl, i'm never quite sure of the limitations of perl regexes, with zero-width preview-matches or whatever), and I doubt that "find all strings that have an odd number of a's and an even number of b's" is his _actual_ problem.

Comment: You probably meant to have a `*` after `([^a]*a[^a]*a)` in regex #1, otherwise the pattern will match only a string with exactly 3 a's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [lookahead expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (here shown as a verbose regex since it really is hard to read, much more on a single line):

```
^                                   # start of string
(?=(?:(?:[^a]*a){2})*[^a]*$)        # assert an even number of as
(?=[^b]*b(?:(?:[^b]*b){2})*[^b]*$)  # assert an odd number of bs
.*                                  # match anything
$                                   # end of string
```

The last two lines can be dropped if you're just validating - they simply match the entire string.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks, is the common practise to put a lookahead in both regex components?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without it being anchored to the end of the line? like if you wanted to match it within "ccccababacccc" with `c+{thing}c+`?

Comment: @user559142: Well, you could remove the second lookahead and put its contents in the place of what's now `.*`. But imagine you add a third or more conditions - this way looks a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: @Random832: I think it needs to be anchored, otherwise the regex would match if a substring fulfils the condition, so it wouldn't enforce oddness/evenness.

Comment: @user559142: You can safely drop the `?:`s at a small performance penalty. Since I'm just using the groups for repetition and don't actually want to capture their contents, I chose to use non-capturing groups `(?:...)` as opposed to capturing groups `(...)` which impose a little extra processing overhead on the regex engine.

Comment: otherwise the regex would match if a substring fulfils the condition - what's the problem? As I see it, it's only a problem if the two lookaheads match _different_ substrings that fulfill the respective conditions. This is the case if you just remove the anchor here, but I was wondering if there is something else you can do to fix that.

Comment: If you replaced the anchors by `c+`, then `cccabbabccccab` would match even though the `a`s are odd and the `b`s are even - because `cccabbabccc` matches and the following `ab` are ignored (unless you tell your programming language to match the entire string - not all of them can. Java can, Python can't).

Comment: @Tim - Why is this not working? ^(?=ABC$)(?=DEF$).*$

I want to find all strings that contain ABC and DEF. I know there is an easier way to do this but I am just doing it for learning purposes....

Comment: @user559142: You need `^(?=.*ABC)(?=.*DEF).*$`, otherwise you're asking the regex to match a string that *consists entirely of*  `ABC` and `DEF` which is impossible.